# get a new string unless a value equals false java

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm currently making a spigot plugin that randomly spawns a user on join. In main, I have two methods. `getLocationList` and `getRandomStringFromList`.

```
public String getRandomStringFromList(List<String> list) {
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(list.size());
    String randomString = list.get(randomNumber);

    return randomString;
}
private List<String> locationList;

public List<String> getLocationList() {
    if (this.locationList == null)
        this.locationList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.locationList = locationList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return this.locationList;
}
```

Then, in my event class, I have this.

```
RandomSpawn plugin;

public RSEvent(RandomSpawn instance) {
    plugin = instance;
}
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoinEvent(PlayerJoinEvent e) {

    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    String randomString = plugin.getRandomStringFromList(plugin.getLocationList());

    p.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(String.valueOf(plugin.getConfig().getString("locations." + randomString + ".world"))),
        plugin.getConfig().getDouble("locations." + randomString + ".x"),
        plugin.getConfig().getDouble("locations." + randomString + ".y"),
        plugin.getConfig().getDouble("locations." + randomString + ".z"),
        plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + randomString + ".yaw"),
        plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + randomString + ".pitch")));
```

This works perfectly, however, I'm adding a disable command. So in config, a new default is made on each location called disabled. This can be set to true or false. I want the plugin to check if `randomString.disabled` is set to true, if so, rerun the whole `getRandomStringFromList` thing to get a new `randomString` until disabled is set to false.

Comment: Just a minor remark: the indentation in your `getLocationList` suggests that you want to do two things in the if statement. Because you did not use brackets, only the first line is executed conditionally. Because the `stream.collect` constructs a new List anyway, you don't need that `new ArrayList` part.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "reset `randomString`"?

Comment: rerun the whole getRandomStringFromList thing to get a new randomstring.

Comment: Look at the bigger picture: _What_ are you attempting to accomplish by doing all of this? Randomized spawns with a default? There's a better approach to be taken here.

Comment: So, to.phrase your requirement slightly differently: you want to select a random string of which the location is not disabled? I recommend doing filtering separately and then run a `getRandomStringFromList` on that.

Comment: How would I filter it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpreted your question to read that you want to select a random location, represented by a string, from a list. However, any location that is disabled (stored elsewhere) should never be selected.

Your approach was to select a random location, check if it is disabled and if so, try again. Repeat until a location that is not disabled pops up. This is not a good idea.
*What if all locations are disabled?* → endless loop
*What if only one of many locations is enabled?* → many locations are needlessly tested

A better approach would be to take your list of locations, filter them so that only locations that are enabled remain, and then select one randomly. When the list after filtering is empty, you know that you may have a problem (maybe you can select a default location, somehow?).

Filtering a list can be done in an elegant way using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). After [creating](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from our initial list of locations (strings), we can [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) the stream and then [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) those locations [in a new `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--). The filter function can look up if a location is disabled or not.

Here is a small example of filtering that compiles on its own and demonstrates the idea.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

class Filtering {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // a list of strings
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("foo");
        strings.add("bar");
        strings.add("baz");

        // a quick and dirty way of representing if a string is enabled
        HashSet<String> disabled = new HashSet<>();
        disabled.add("bar");

        // filter strings to only enabled ones
        strings.stream()
            .filter(s -> !disabled.contains(s))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

In your code, the changes should probably look something like the following.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoinEvent(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    FileConfiguration cfg = plugin.getConfig();

    // get all enabled locations
    List<String> locations = plugin.getLocationList().stream().
        filter(s -> !cfg.getBoolean("locations." + s + ".disabled")).
        collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (locations.size() === 0) {
        // TODO: handle this special case
    }

    // teleport to random location
    String randomString = plugin.getRandomStringFromList(locations);
    String cfgPrefix = "locations." + randomString + ".";
    p.teleport(new Location(
        Bukkit.getWorld(cfg.getString(cfgPrefix + "world")),
        cfg.getDouble(cfgPrefix + "x"),
        cfg.getDouble(cfgPrefix + "y"),
        cfg.getDouble(cfgPrefix + "z"),
        cfg.getInt(cfgPrefix + "yaw"),
        cfg.getInt(cfgPrefix + "pitch")));
}
```

I introduced some temporary variables to improve readability, got rid of an unnecessary `String.valueOf` call and made minor changes to the formatting. The main change however is the block below `// get all enabled locations`. It should be intuitively clear what is going on there, but please let me know if you need me to clarify anything.